# Using select form helper to fill a hash column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Book.extended_fields = {}

What is the select version of

```
<%= text_field_tag("book[extended_fields][description]", nil, class: "form-control") %>
```

?

I'm looking to create something like

```
<select class="form-control" name="book[extended_fields][description]"></select>
```

This is for a partial that will render a form that uses dynamically created fields.  So, ultimately, it'll be in a loop that's something like:

```
<%= text_field_tag("book[extended_fields][#{k}]", nil, class: "form-control") %>
```

where k represents an item in a collection of fields to be created.

Comment: Why are you trying to build dynamic content with rails and not javascript?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity.  The fields are created based on a hash column in the database (so, they can't have hard-coded unique attributes), but are rendered with the view, not after the view is rendered.

Comment: Ah, ok. Have you tried using collection_select? Something like `<%= collection_select('thing', 'status', @book, :first, :last) %>`

Comment: I think that I'd have the same problem with collection select.  The core of the issue is that the first two arguments are concatenated together to make the name attribute.  So, 

    `collection_select(:post, :author_id, ...)`

gives
    `<select name="post[author_id]" id="post_author_id">`

I needed
    `<select name="post[extended_fields][author_id]" id="post_author_id">`

and didn't understand how to format the arguments in order to get that.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out

Answer (score 0):

To answer your main question, `select_tag` creates the html select option you're looking for. You can find the documentation [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag).

Correct structure should be laid out as such

```
select_tag(name, option_tags = nil, options = {}, {}, {:class => 'form-control'})
```

Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I was trying to use the select helper.  So, I attempted to do something like

Comment: See my comment on the main question, collection select will allow you to use a hash and display your |key, value| options

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting rails instead of using it.  I had been trying to use the select helper and couldn't figure out how to use multiple arguments for the name portion that then get concatenated into the attribute.  The answer was simply to define the name attribute myself.

```
<%= select("book", "description", (options), {include_blank: true}, class: "form-control", name: "book[extended_fields][description]") %>
```